# How to set menu to toolbar in android that should display in fragment

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I have created a toolbar which is used in whole android app. Now I have to add menu item to the common toolbar.And I am following MVVM architecture.

menu_sort.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sortToolBar"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/common_tool_bar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"/>

</menu>
```

And Even I added below code in fragment
And even  I added

setHasOptionMenu(true)

fragment.xml

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sort, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `setHasOptionsMenu` flag as true on the fragment `onCreate` method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```